# Zero inflated Poisson Regression Model distribution function derivation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, density-function, poisson-regression, zero-inflation

Is it possible to provide hints on how to get the probability distribution as shown below:

[image: probability distribution from wikipedia]

Additionally from a different online source, they mention the case about hte logistic submodel = the intercept of the logit model, how does that fact there help? (picture 2)

[image: picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two random variables Z and Y, such that $ Z \sim Bernoulli(1 - \pi) $, $ Y | Z = 0 $ is $0$ with probability $1$, and $ Y | Z = 1 \sim Poisson(\lambda). $ Then $ Y \sim ZIP(\pi, \lambda) $.

Marginalize over $Z$ (it's an easy sum) to get the PMF.

Comment: Just wondering how you go about showing the variance of Y:

Comment: $$Var[Y] = Var[E[Y|Z]] + E[Var[Y|Z]], how do you evaluate the E[Y|Z] and Var[Y|Z] respectively?

Comment: also is it possible to clarify Y|Z = 0 is 0 with probability 1?? @Jason

Comment: Given that Z = 0, Y is 0 with probability 1, so the expected value is 0 and the variance is 0.

Given that Z = 1, Y ~ Pois(lambda), so the expected value is lambda and the variance is lambda too.

So now we can write E(Y | Z) = lambda * Z, and Var(Y | Z) as the same. Both are functions of Z. Now finding Var(Y) is a straightforward application of the formula you mentioned.

Comment: As for clarifying Y | Z = 0, I'm not sure what else there is to say. Given Z = 0, Y follows a point mass distribution located at 0. That is, for any omega in the sample space, Y(omega) = 0.

Comment: As you can see from my answer, the way to think about a ZIP distribution is that it represents the final outcome of two processes. The first is a coin flip to determine whether it's possible for a nonzero outcome to happen at all. If it comes up as 1, then a nonzero outcome is possible, and the outcome follows a Poisson distribution. You can "zero-inflate" any distribution (but doing it to a Bernoulli would be a bit silly).